# numpy slices using column dependent end index from an integer array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

If I have an array and I apply summation

```
arr = np.array([[1.,1.,2.],[2.,3.,4.],[4.,5.,6]])
np.sum(arr,axis=1)
```

I get the total along the three rows ([4.,9.,15.])

My complication is that arr contains data that may be bad after a certain column index. I have an integer array that tells me how many "good" values I have in each row and I want to sum/average over the good values. Say:

```
ngoodcols=np.array([0,1,2])
np.sum(arr[:,0:ngoodcols],axis=1)  # not legit but this is the idea
```

It is clear how to do this in a loop, but is there a way to sum only that many, producing [0.,2.,9.] without resorting to looping? Equivalently, I could use nansum if I knew how to set the elements in column indexes higher than b equal to np.nan, but this is a nearly equivalent problem as far as slicing is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use [masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1., 1., 2.], [2., 3., 4.], [4., 5., 6]])
ngoodcols = np.array([0, 1, 2])
mask = ngoodcols[:, np.newaxis] <= np.arange(arr.shape[1])
arr_masked = np.ma.masked_array(arr, mask)
print(arr_masked)
# [[-- -- --]
#  [2.0 -- --]
#  [4.0 5.0 --]]
print(arr_masked.sum(1))
# [-- 2.0 9.0]
```

Note that here when there are not good values you get a "missing" value as a result, which may or may not be useful for you. Also, a masked array also allows you to easily do other operations that only apply for valid values (mean, etc.).

Another simple option is to just multiply by the mask:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1., 1., 2.], [2., 3., 4.], [4., 5., 6]])
ngoodcols = np.array([0, 1, 2])
mask = ngoodcols[:, np.newaxis] <= np.arange(arr.shape[1])
print((arr * ~mask).sum(1))
# [0. 2. 9.]
```

Here when there are no good values you just get zero.

Comment: Also a shout-out to Austin's answer, which uses the same arange trick with nan values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using Boolean indexing. This sets elements in column indexes higher than ones in `ngoodcols` equal to `np.nan` and use `np.nansum`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1.,1.,2.],[2.,3.,4.],[4.,5.,6]])
ngoodcols = np.array([0,1,2])

arr[np.asarray(ngoodcols)[:,None] <= np.arange(arr.shape[1])] = np.nan

print(np.nansum(arr, axis=1))
# [ 0.  2.  9.]
```